# Spring boot multi module - Reload sub modules without running maven install

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot multi module maven project configured with a parent pom, a web application and a sub module that the web project is dependent on.

Is there an eclipse plugin that I can use that will allow me to make a change in the sub module, and then have that change reflected when I restart the web application without running maven install on the sub module every time?

```
pom.xml
    |
    Web Application
    pom.xml
    |
    Sub Module
    pom.xml
```

I am starting the application in eclipse with the run configuration goal: spring-boot:run

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not necessary to install any plugins to resolve this. Just right click on the project you want to run then select Run Configurations, then select Resolve Workspace artifacts.

[image]